# Google Cloud Logs Export Names

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to configure the names of the files exported from Logging?

Currently the file exported includes colons. This are invalid characters as a path element in hadoop, so PySpark for instance cannot read these files. Obviously the easy solution is to rename the files, but this interferes with syncing.

Is there a way to configure the names or change them to no include colons? Any other solutions are appreciated. Thanks!

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/site/markdown/filesystem/introduction.md

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there is no way to change the naming convention when exporting log files as this process is automated on the backend.

If you would like to request to have this feature available in GCP, I would suggest creating a [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com). This page allows you to report bugs and request new features to be implemented within GCP.